# Spyder - kernel dies when using sys.exit()

Tags: python, spyder

I'm running a simulation in pygame, where clicking on close button triggers `sys.exit()`. If I run it from command prompt then all is nice and well. If I try to run the script from Spyder everything works fine until I click on close button:

```py
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2971: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)

Kernel died, restarting
```

After this the sim window becomes unresponsive and I have to manually kill it. The same issue has happened previously as well when I ran tkinter-based scripts from Spyder and closed window by clicking on X.

I had a look around but couldn't find a solution either here or on Spyder's github page. Does anyone know what's causing it?

EDIT: Just tested - if I just do in the console:

```py
import sys
sys.exit()
```

I get the same warning, but kernel doesn't crash.

Comment: Are you using Qt?

Comment: In pygame code I'm trying to run? I'm not using any gui modules, just vanilla pygame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This will no longer be an issue in Spyder 4, to be released later in this month (November 2019).